# Need a JavaScript IF Statement for Grading System

Tags: javascript

I need someone to show me how to try add an IF statement after the user put's in their grade, the statement needs to display the alert right at the end if the mark is greater than 100 or less than 0. I've tried many different things and really not sure how to present this at all. If anyone could show me how to do it would be great.

```
var mark;
var grade;
grade = "Not Yet Graded";

mark = prompt( "Please input the mark(%)" );
mark = parseInt( mark, 10 ); // see comment



if( mark > 70 )
{
grade = "First Class";
}
else if( mark > 60 )
{
grade = "Upper Second";
}
else if( mark > 50 )
{
grade = "Lower Second";
}
else if( mark > 40 )
{
grade = "Third Class";
}

else if( mark < 40 )
{
grade = "Fail";
}


alert( "Mark: " + mark + "% - Grade: " + grade );
}
else 
{
alert( "Invalid mark, outside range 0-100" );
}
```

Comment: You tagged this "Java" but the code looks like JavaScript, which is a completely different language. Do you really mean Java or is it JavaScript?

Comment: think so i'm new and my teachers are useless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check your value bounds before you begin grading like

```
if (mark < 0 || mark > 100)
{
alert('Invalid mark, outside range 0-100');
}
else if (mark > 70)
{
  grade = 'First Class';
} 
else if (mark > 60)
{
  grade = 'Upper Second';
} 
else if (mark > 50)
{
  grade = 'Lower Second';
} 
else if (mark > 40)
{
  grade = 'Third Class';
} 
else if (mark <= 40)
{
  grade = 'Fail';
}
```

Also, notice that you either need `mark >= 40` for third class or mark the user's grade as fail if `mark <= 40`. Otherwise, you'll miss grading when the score is `40`.

At the end, you can simply check if the `grade` was initialized or not to show the grade alert.

```
if (grade != null)
{
  alert('Mark: ' + mark + '% - Grade: ' + grade);
}
```

Comment: @libik Please, care for a review? :)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
var mark;
var grade;
grade = "Not Yet Graded";

mark = prompt( "Please input the mark(%)" );
mark = parseInt( mark, 10 ); // see comment

if (mark>100) grade="unclassified";
else if( mark > 70 ) grade = "First Class";
else if( mark > 60 ) grade = "Upper Second";
else if( mark > 50 ) grade = "Lower Second";
else if( mark > 40 ) grade = "Third Class"
else if( mark >= 0 ) grade = "Fail";
else grade="unclassified";

if (grade!="unclassified") alert( "Mark: " + mark + "% - Grade: " + grade );
else alert( "Invalid mark, outside range 0-100" );
```

It first checks for a mark over 100. All the `elseif`'s will fail as soon as one of the `if` clause's makes it. It stored 'unclassified' as the grade. The grade of fail is given to any score 0 to 40 inclusive, if this fails, grade is defaulted to unclassified. We now break out of the loop and evaluate `grade` separately - if it is not 'unclassified' then the mark was valid, and we alert the grade, if 'grade' is equal to 'unclassified' then the alert says so with 'Invalid mark, outside range 0-100'.

One more thing, in JavaScript if there is only one line of code after a comparision, you do not need to use curly brackets {}, so instead of:

```
else if( mark > 60 ) {grade = "Upper Second";}
```

we can use:

```
else if( mark > 60 ) grade = "Upper Second";
```

(although this isn't true for functions which needs {} regardless of the number of lines in the function body.)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is failing because you are not checking whether the mark is below (or equal to) 100 and above (or equal to) 0. This way if you get 110 you get first class while if you get -10 you get fail.

You just need to make sure that there the mark is smaller or equal to 100 in the first series of if, greater or equal to 0 in the last if, and then before alerting that the mark is once more between 0 and 100 (included) before you print what you want to print. Do it like this :

```
if( mark > 70 && mark <= 100)
{
grade = "First Class";
}
else if( mark > 60 && mark <= 100)
{
grade = "Upper Second";
}
else if( mark > 50 && mark <= 100)
{
grade = "Lower Second";
}
else if( mark > 40 && mark <= 100)
{
grade = "Third Class";
}

else if( mark < 40 && mark >= 0)
{
grade = "Fail";
}

if (mark <= 100 && mark >= 0) {
alert( "Mark: " + mark + "% - Grade: " + grade );
}
else 
{
alert( "Invalid mark, outside range 0-100" );
}
```

OR You could also do (checking if the mark is between 0 and 100 only in the beginning):

```
if (mark >= 0 && mark <= 100) {
   if( mark > 70)
    {
    grade = "First Class";
    }
    else if( mark > 60)
    {
    grade = "Upper Second";
    }
    else if( mark > 50)
    {
    grade = "Lower Second";
    }
    else if( mark > 40)
    {
    grade = "Third Class";
    }
    
    else if( mark < 40)
    {
    grade = "Fail";
    }
    }
else {
alert( "Invalid mark, outside range 0-100" );
}
    if (mark <= 100 && mark >= 0) {
    alert( "Mark: " + mark + "% - Grade: " + grade );
    }
```